# Using MySQL and Windows Forms Application C++ CLI

Tags: c++, mysql, winforms, c++-cli

I am using C++ CLI Windows Forms Application and connecting to MySQL database on my system itself.

I would like to know how to make the connection secure between the application and the database.

I am using the following constring for connection.

```
String^ constring = L"datasource=localhost;port=3306;username=****;password=****; SslMode=Required";
```

Is my connection secure? Or do I need to do something else as well.

The MySQL Database in Workbench shows it is Standard TCP/IP protocol and No SSL certificate is attached

Comment: I think username, password and SSLMode are enough to ensure security, Moreover, you may be able to add allowed IP addresses to the database. That should be enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the String you have mentioned SSLMode is required then I suppose it should be secure

Comment: I know but how do I check if it is secure